# object of type 'int' has no len() error when calling the from_dict() from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api, dictionary

Here's my code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as ul
import json

api_key = ''
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(api_key)}
search_api_url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search'
params = {'term': 'coffee', 
          'location': 'Brooklyn, New York',
          'limit': 50}
# set timeout = 5 to stop Requests from waiting for a response after 5 seconds.
response = requests.get(search_api_url, headers=headers, params=params, timeout=5)

print(response.url)
print(response.status_code)

data = response.json()
print(type(data))
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df
```

Here's the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
      2 df = df.transpose()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1677, in DataFrame.from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1674     raise ValueError("only recognize index or columns for orient")
   1676 if orient != "tight":
-> 1677     return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
   1678 else:
   1679     realdata = data["data"]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:721, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    716     if columns is not None:
    717         # error: Argument 1 to "ensure_index" has incompatible type
    718         # "Collection[Any]"; expected "Union[Union[Union[ExtensionArray,
    719         # ndarray], Index, Series], Sequence[Any]]"
    720         columns = ensure_index(columns)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
--> 721     arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
    722         # error: Argument 3 to "nested_data_to_arrays" has incompatible
    723         # type "Optional[Collection[Any]]"; expected "Optional[Index]"
    724         data,
    725         columns,
    726         index,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    727         dtype,
    728     )
    729     mgr = arrays_to_mgr(
    730         arrays,
    731         columns,
   (...)
    734         typ=manager,
    735     )
    736 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:519, in nested_data_to_arrays(data, columns, index, dtype)
    516 if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
    517     columns = ensure_index(data[0]._fields)
--> 519 arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
    520 columns = ensure_index(columns)
    522 if index is None:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:873, in to_arrays(data, columns, dtype)
    870     return arrays, columns
    872 if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 873     arr = _list_to_arrays(data)
    874 elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
    875     arr, columns = _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:894, in _list_to_arrays(data)
    891     content = lib.to_object_array_tuples(data)
    892 else:
    893     # list of lists
--> 894     content = lib.to_object_array(data)
    895 return content

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2915, in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array()

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

As you can see, I made an API call to get some sample data from Yelp's fusion api. The data turned out to already be in a dictionary. In the last lines of code, I tried to read it into a pandas dataframe but it gave me this error. Would appreciate any help to work around this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in `data`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nick It's just a mask I'm using, bound to the dictionary here